# Canadian eTA with US visa

Tags: canada, eta, brazilian-citizens

I will apply for a Canadian ETA since I have an American visa and I'm eligible to. In this process, will I need to submit my passport to a Canadian embassy or will the ETA be digitally linked to it?

Second question: My visa will expire in ~5 months, so I will apply a new one. Should I wait to have my new passport to apply for my eTA? Is the eTA linked to the passport and becomes invalid after a passport renewal?

Useful information:I have Brazilian citizenship.

Comment: By American visa, do you mean that you have a green card?

Comment: @blackbird No, I mean a standard tourism visa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your eTA is electronically linked to your passport (that's the "e": "electronic), so you will not need to submit your passport. Note that you must enter Canada [by air](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eta/facts.html) in this circumstance; you'll need a visitor visa to enter "by car, bus, train, or boat, including a cruise ship."

However, an eTA "[is valid for up to five (5) years or until the passport expires, whichever comes first](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/questions-answers-by-topic.asp?st=16.7)." If your passport is expiring soon, you may want to renew that first, or you'll have to get a new eTA again after.